# Can I write a UX/UI Case Study without User Research?

Tags: ux-designer, selling-ux

I work in a software development agency and we have very tight deadlines of delivering designs. Mostly the people in the leadership talk to the clients and give me the product brief. Since it's a very small start up, there are no resources or time for conducting user research. I want to present my work in my portfolio but I'm confused if I can show case studies of real-life projects without any user research data. How can I present my case studies in best possible way under these circumstances?